# python setup tools console_scripts with arguments

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to implement my pypy.py script on commandline, I need to work with setup tools but the console_script does not work properly as my pypy.py needs two arguments, please guide me how can I modify it properly to work on commendline.

python.py

```
def main(agru1, argu2):

    "do something"

 if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

when I include it in my setup.py file, as console_script as follow

```
setup( 
     entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['pypy = pypy.pypy:main'],
    }

)
```

And I get the following error when I run it on commandline:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/python", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('Pypy==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pypy')()
TypeError: main() takes at least 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: You are meant to get the arguments from ``sys.argv``. They are not passed in. You can apply the argument parsing library to it to make it deal with options etc etc.

Answer (score 28):

The entry point must be a function that may be invoked using *exactly zero* arguments.  If you want to pass in arguments from the command line, say you want to invoke it like:

```
$ pypy a1 a2
```

You need to read them from [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv) instead.  So your python module should contain this:

```
def program(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

def main():
    import sys
    arg1, arg2 = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    program(arg1, arg2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Alternatively, the `main` function may instead take an `argv` argument that defaults to `sys.argv` if importing `sys` is desirable at the top level of the module:

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    program(argv[1], argv[2])
```

Running that command as above should print out `a1 a2` into the console.  Error handling on user input is your own exercise.

Comment: Thanks, how should I include main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]) in the setup.py ( as mentioned above) ?

error still the same if I use your explanation .... !

Comment: `setup.py` hooks into either `distutils` or `setuptools` and the underlying library have their own handling of `sys.argv` to process the commands, which will almost certainly clash with however you want to do this.  Have you tried running my code as is?

Comment: Yes I have after that I responded and its the same error as mentioned above in the question.

Comment: Right, your setup.py calls main directly, not the _script_ directly as such; So modify the `main` method to not take anything and pass it to the actual program with the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answer of metatoaster, instead of using `sys.argv` you can use `argsparse` https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html, which makes the passing of argumnets a bit more user-friendly.

```
import argparse


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--arg1', help='arg1 help')
  parser.add_argument('--arg2', help='arg2 help')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  print("arg1 {}, arg2 {}".format(args.arg1, args.arg2)
```

Call it like:

```
pypy --arg1 1 --arg2 2
```

Comment: While this is a clear example of using argparse it doesn't address how to use it in context of a `setup.py` using _console_script_.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if it is modified to use an entrypoint function, rather than the `if __name__ == "__main__"` method. The options here are to modify your entrypoint function to get args from sys.argv(as in the accepted answer), or argparse. Using argparse is more pythonic, and it works with console_script.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was facing a similar problem. The way I solved it was by calling the script directly using `python -m <complete_script_path> arg1 arg2`.

For example if my script file name is bar and it is present inside the package foo and the contents are as follows:

**foo.py**

```
def f1(a,b):
    return a+b
if __name__=="__main__":
   a = sys.argv[1]
   b = sys.argv[2]
   f1(a,b)
```

I can invoke foo as follows:

```
python -m foo.bar arg1 arg2
```

I dont have to pass it as a console_script inside `setup` function of `setuptools`.This solves problem of not being able to pass arguments to console scripts. Also I can package it inside the whl file during distribution.