# Can pip/setuptools console scripts pass python options to python itself?

Tags: python, pip, argparse, setuptools, pdb

For example, using `-m` for pdb and post-mortem debugging, you can do:

`python -m pdb script.py arg1 --kwarg`

(say for instance that `arg1` and `kwarg` are parsed from `sys.argv` with the `argparse` module).

A CLI tool can be created with pip/setuptools' entry points:

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "toolname = my_project.script:main"
        ]
    },
)
```

Now after installing `pip install my_project`, `toolname` can be used instead of `python /path/to/script.py`. Is it possible to pass arguments directly to python - like `-m` to invoke `pdb`?

Edit:

Unlike [python setup tools console_scripts with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753946/python-setup-tools-console-scripts-with-arguments) I know how to pass arguments to the script, and I'm looking for how to pass arguments to python itself.

The `python -m pdb $(which myscript)` method, used in [How to start debugger with an entry_point script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930920/how-to-start-debugger-with-an-entry-point-script) is pretty good, but it only works if the script actually calls `main()` when executed (script may be from a third-party library).

`python -c "import pdb, pkg_resources; pdb.run('pkg_resources.load_entry_point(\'mylocalpkg\', \'console_scripts\', \'myscript\')()')"` supports more scripts and platforms, but I'm not sure if it works for other python options other than `-m pdb`.

Comment: "Is it possible to pass arguments directly to python - like `-m` to invoke `pdb`?" The arguments passed would be handled directly by your script, your script will have full control and view of all arguments, including invoking `pdb` at specifc step; alternatively if you want to start the `toolname` script with `-m pdb` the other answer linked has the answer.  It was not clear from the question which of the two you want.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find the `entry_points` answer (I was searching for console scripts). It's fairly close, and helps my problem, thanks!